Energy Generator with Magnets and Springs
I would like to build a prototype mechanism that utilizes neodymium magnets and springs to generate mechanical energy. The magnets will be placed inside a PVC tube, and the springs will act as repelling elements, causing the magnets to oscillate.
Components
Neodymium magnets: N42, diameter 22 mm, height 10 mm.
Springs: Spring constant 20.85 N/mm, free length 50.80 mm.
PVC tube: Inner diameter 25 mm, length 150 mm.
Theoretical Analysis
Calculation of repulsive force between magnets:
Neodymium magnets have significant repulsive force, which depends on their distance and surface area.
The repulsive force


F
m
​
between two magnets can be estimated using a simplified model:



0
⋅

1
⋅

2
4

⋅

2
F
m
​
4π⋅r
2
μ
0
​
⋅m
1
​
⋅m
2
​
​
where:

0
μ
0
​
is the magnetic permeability of free space (
4

×
1
0
−
7
H/m
4π×10
−7
H/m),

1
m
1
​
and

2
m
2
​
are the magnetic moments of the magnets,

r is the distance between the magnets.
Calculation of spring force:
The spring force


F
s
​
is calculated using Hooke's law:



⋅

F
s
​
=k⋅x
where:

k is the spring constant (20.85 N/mm),

x is the displacement of the spring.
Force balance:
For dynamic equilibrium, the repulsive force of the magnets should be balanced by the spring force:




F
m
​
=F
s
​
Simulation
A simulation of the oscillatory motion of the magnets inside the PVC tube was conducted using mathematical tools. The simulation shows how the magnets move over time under the influence of repulsive and spring forces.
Simulation results:
The magnets move in an oscillatory manner, as predicted by theoretical analysis.
The motion of the magnets is stable and regular.
Question
Does such a mechanism, based on the described principles of magnetism and elasticity, have a basis and can it work in practice? Are there any factors that could significantly affect its operation or efficiency?

Won't friction cause this to find an eventual equilibrium position?

A spring will make something oscillate just fine without magnets.  Not sure what you're trying to do by opposing the spring with a magnet.  An oscillating magnet can be used to create electricity, it's basically how generators work, but you need some outside force to cause the oscillation.

It sounds like you are trying to make a perpetual motion machine. That won't work.
You are not going to get more energy out of this than you put in, (which would violate thermodynamics).
One source of loss here would be that a spring being elastically deformed will heat up due to internal friction. That friction will sap energy from the oscillation. Air resistance in the tube will also sap energy from the oscillation.
Mathematical simulations are not perfect, rounding errors can result in energy being added to the model that would not be added to the real-life model.

You cannot harvest continuous mechanical work from any scheme using permanent magnets that rotate or oscillate. In physics terms this can be proven mathematically knowing only that the divergence of the magnetic field is zero.
